# Unable to delete the file in a directory

Tags: php, file

I used `unlink()` to delete the files inside `"galleryphoto/".$username` directory in my server. But every time I execute ,the file doesn't get deleted. I am unable to figure out what is the mistake.Since the coding is a PHP page which is called by another page in PHP by jquery AJAX, i can't see the error. Please help me!

```
<?php
           include('session.php');
               include('db.php');
               $new_user_id =$_SESSION['user_id'];
               $cod= mysql_query("select user_login_id from user where user_id ='$new_user_id'");
                $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($cod);
                $username = $row['user_login_id'];
                if(isset($_POST['file']) && is_array($_POST['file']))
                {
                       $path = 'galleryphoto/'.$username;
                     $name = $_POST['file'];


              foreach($name as $file1)
                 {  
                   unlink($path."/".$file1) or die("Failed to delete file");
               print_r(error_get_last());
                  }
                   //header("location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //redirect after deleting files so the user can refresh without that resending post info message
               }

 ?>
        <form name="form1"  action="" method="post">
          <?php
       //$path1='galleryphoto/'.$username;

       $path = "galleryphoto/".$username;



            $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");
       while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
          if($file == "index.php")
        continue;
           if($file == ".")
           continue;
            if($file == "..")
        continue;
      echo "<input type='CHECKBOX' name='file[]' value='$path/$file'>";
  // echo "<a href=$path/$file>$file<br><img src=$path/$file border=0></a><br>"; 
     echo "<img src='$path/$file' alt='$file' border=0 height=300px width=300px><br />";
     }
        closedir($dir_handle);
     ?>
        <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">
     </form>
```

Comment: try using the absolute path to the file you want to delete

Comment: Are you sure that the webuser / the user executing the php scripts have permission to delete the files?

Comment: i also changed the permission with the help of chmod("galleryphoto/".$username,0755); from file permission of 0777. Still the file doesnt get deleted.

Comment: Why are you  declaring `$path` twice ?

Comment: Ah... You're sending the relative path as POST value `<input type='CHECKBOX' name='file[]' value='$path/$file'>` and you're adding the relative path again in your `foreach` in `unlink($path."/".$file1)`... You can remove either one ...

Comment: Add following code in top of php file  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);    Then you will get error discription.

Comment: i removed one still. Its doesnt get deleted

Comment: @SunnyAttwal ya inlcuded it now, but since its AJAX its not showing anything .!it just returning back to the page .php from where AJAX request was sent

Answer (score 0):

try to use php [realpath](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.realpath.php)

```
unlink(realpath($fileName));
```

Comment: may be the $path hasn't the good value to your file.
check if galleryphoto/ is in the same directory with your script.